# Is it possible to bleed the brakes with one caliper detached from its carrier?

Tags: brake-calipers, bleeding

I'm in the process of changing a disc(rotor) and the new disc will take a week to arrive. I had some brake fluid leakage due to a piston dust boot that had slipped out, I removed the piston and replaced the O seal and put the piston and boot back in place hence I need to bleed. While waiting for the disc is there anyway I can bleed the brakes with this caliper/piston removed, I am also waiting on new caliper carrier bolts as others had to be cut off so I can't fix the carrier on yet either.

I mean when I pump the brake pedal during bleeding the detached  calipers piston will just pop out, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, put a wood block to stop the pistons moving too far.

Acts just like a pair of pads and a disc.

Comment: And this is acceptable, what happens when you remove the blocks?

Comment: @AndyS you will be putting the brakes back together correctly won’t you?